# How to properly set time to JSpinner in Java?

Tags: java, netbeans, time, jspinner

I want to set my JSpinner in Neatbeans swing with the current time, and allow user to choose time through clicking the arrows up and down. I have these code which somehow works at first but cannot change the time when clicking the arrows. Here's my code:

```
JSpinner spinner = new JSpinner();
spinner.setModel(new SpinnerDateModel());
mySpinnerControl.setEditor(new JSpinner.DateEditor(spinner, "HH:mm"));
```

When i click the arrow keys, time wont change and got this error message:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: javax.swing.SpinnerNumberModel cannot be cast to javax.swing.SpinnerDateModel
```

What is wrong with my code? I researched through net and they all have the same code.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks ahead.

Comment: For better help, please show us an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). There could be any number of problems.

Comment: im sorry im new to java programming..what do you mean by the code that throws exception? do you mean the whole error message? or my code?

Comment: Actually, see my edited comment. (Refresh the page.) And yes, your code. When the exception is thrown, it will have a line number.

Comment: But there are actually several things I can think of that could be the mistake so a runnable example would be best. All of your code if it's short, and if it's longer, you should reduce it as best you can.

Answer (score 2):

What is `mySpinnerControl`? I could get your example to work when I changed `mySpinnerControl` to `spinner`. My guess is that you set the editor on another component, and thus `spinner` still uses a Number-Editor which then produces the exception when it tries to set the date/time value.

The following code worked for me:

```
public class Spinner extends JFrame {
    public Spinner() {

        JSpinner spinner = new JSpinner();
        spinner.setModel(new SpinnerDateModel());
        spinner.setEditor(new JSpinner.DateEditor(spinner, "HH:mm"));

        getContentPane().add(spinner, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Spinner f = new Spinner();
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Comment: I dont know how to term this, but I am using swing controls in netbeans. mySpinnerControl is my swing control with that variable name. I get the control at the pallete pane of netbeans..

Answer (score 0):

..i finally make it worked! I just used the following 2 line codes:

```
mySpinnerControl.setModel(new SpinnerDateModel());
mySpinnerControl.setEditor(new JSpinner.DateEditor(mySpinnerControl, "HH:mm"));
```

But thank you really for your response @cello and @Radiodef.. very much appreciated you guys!

Answer (score 0):

Before I write for JSpinner let me tell you to use Date function as below.

```
  Date d1 = new Date(0);
  Calendar cl = Calendar. getInstance();       
  cl.setTime(d1);      
  System.out.println("today is " + d1.toString());
```

Then there is JSpinner which can be used as follows.Changing the format to only "dd" can give you the date.To manipulate it convert it using integer parser(the commented out lines).

```
SimpleDateFormat formaterD = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"); 
String  spinnerDate=formaterD.format(testSpin.getValue());
//int z=Integer.parseInt(spinnerValue);
System.out.println(spinnerDate);
//System.out.println("Date in integer format:"+z);

//To err is Human!Please comment if I'm wrong.
```